# Floating Action Button not display the source Image in Android Studio..?

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

Floating Action Button not display source image[This Image contain the example for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrMIM.png)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure "src" is set to FloatingActionButton.

and use `app:tint="@null"`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `app:srcCompat` is set to your image you're trying to display.

For example:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Shows this `FloatingActionButton`:

[image: Floating Email Action Button]

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and I solved it by:

```
android:foreground="@drawable/map"
```